# Questions about y=x and the equal sign...

Tags: notation

Should it technically be said that in $y=x$, the equal sign means $y$ is *determined* by $x$?  Or rather, that $y$ is a mirror of, or reflection of, $x$?

These are obviously both extremely different notions.

Is $\mathbb{R}$ the default domain of x unless specified otherwise?

Could $y=x$ be considered a mathematical model of a line?

Comment: It depends on context. If you say "Consider the set of all points $(x, y)$ in the plane such that $y = x$", this would give you a line. On the other hand, if you have already defined $y$ and $x$ and then write $y = x$, you would be stating that under the previously given definitions of $y$ and $x$, one can show that $y = x$. In higher level math, $\mathbb{R}$ is rarely the "default domain" of any variable unless the author specifies it to be so.

Comment: Thanks... Good clarification.  Would you say $y$ is determined by $x$ here; or rather $y$ is a mirror of, or reflection of $x$?

Comment: I'm not sure what it would  mean to "be a mirror of $x$", mathematically speaking. But it would make sense to say that $y$ is actually a function $y(x) = x$ (that is, that $y$ is determined by $x$).

Comment: But in set theory, isn’t $x$ and $y$ just a bivalent pairing, in which case the equal sign means “in the case of $x$ being this value, $y$ is this value?”